# How can I attach an existing server image to an image field rather than uploading a new image file?

Tags: media

Is there a module or some other way of attaching an image to an image field by selecting the image from existing files on the server rather than upload a new image?

I'm working on a project where many nodes have an image field. That image is displayed in various places at different sizes using image styles.

The users are migrating from another system and they're very used to the "image library" concept. They like to upload images that they will later use in various places around the site. The standard image field on a node only lets you upload from the local file system.

Ideally we'd like to have a "browse server" button instead of the upload button but end up with the same resulting image field.

The Media module comes tantalizingly close and I'm sure we'll use it for videos etc but it creates a media asset field, not an image field which I don't think can be resized with image styles and used so easily in views etc.

I tried the image picker module late last night. Maybe I need to try it again but I don't think I quite understood it. We don't really want resizing and create thumbnails etc on the node edit screen. We really just want a way to create an image field where the path points to an existing file somewhere below /sites/default/files. The files will be uploaded with something like IMCE.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: This question is open again for Drupal 8, where the answers below do not seem to be working (yet)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [Filefield Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) along with [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) does what you need.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thanks.

The other answers sound good too.

Comment: Thank you for recommending this. This is just a wonderful module. It even looks cleaner in page edit screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [IMCE for filefield](http://drupal.org/project/imce_filefield) that was just released. IMCE for File Field allows users to select files from IMCE File Browser for file fields. It supports FTP uploaded files by automatically registering them as IMCE files thus making them usable in a file field.

Answer (score 2):

The Media module is also useful for images, but you can also use a regular image field and use the Media widget to upload or select images from the server. The field remains the same, only the way for the image to get inputted changes. I believe you even have the possibility to search and filter in the widget that comes with Media module 2.x

Comment: [Media 2.x](https://drupal.org/project/media) is the new hotness, yes. The same file can be re-used in multiple places. The Media file selector widget allows users to choose an existing uploaded file, or upload a new one.